# I'm travelling to USA for business (B1/B2). My wife is accompanying me for tourism with B1/B2 visa. What documents does she need for immigration?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

First the facts.

1. I am an Indian. I have a US B1/B2 visa. I have traveled with it twice in the past for business meetings. My trip was sponsored by my then employer both times earlier.
2. I am going to travel to the US for a third time now for business meetings. This trip is also sponsored by my employer. I will stay 29 days in the US. My employer has booked the trip tickets, return tickets and hotels for me.
3. My wife is an Indian. My wife also has a US B1/B2 visa. She has travelled once in the past for business meetings. The trip was sponsored by her then employer.
4. My wife is travelling with me to the US now to accompany me. She will stay with me for 29 days.
5. My wife is unemployed now.
6. My wife has booked her flight tickets. She has however not booked hotels because she is going to stay in the same hotels as mine. The hotels are booked in my name by my current employer.
7. My wife and I are travelling together in the same flights and arriving at the US at the same time together.
8. My employer is providing sufficient documents (port of entry letter, laptop details letter, business meeting invitation letter, etc.) to me for immigration check.

My questions.

1. What documents does my wife need to carry with her so that her entry into the US is smooth?
2. Do you have any other general suggestions for a trip like this that I should be aware of?

Comment: Wow. Is this the best written up question we got, ever?

Answer (score 6):

If you will be traveling together which I recommend, she needs to carry very little. A copy of your marriage certificate in reality is all she may need. Every reasonable immigration officer you will meet at the airport will know you'll be staying as a couple. Your wife being unemployed is not a big deal particularly as she's a married woman. People understand that there are many women who stay at home and don't work. It is not unusual, including in the USA.

If you want to be over abundantly cautious, a copy of your **personal** bank statements, return tickets and proof of ties to India. Having a decent enough job in India that sends you on business to the USA is good proof of ties plus the documents your company is providing.

If you're a young couple without children back home, just be polite and assertive and make the I/O understand you have a good life back home you won't trade to come and live here illegally. Yes there have been horror stories about visitors at airports in the past months, however the vast majority of visitors don't experience what we read about.

Comment: Good answer, but "assertive" may be too strong a word.  Perhaps "firm" is better.  Even then, it's probably best not to be firm unless or until firmness is warranted.